# Searching for files on multiple servers

Tags: domain-name-system

Is it possible to instruct a server to search for a file at 1 IP and ***if not found*** to search another IP before returning 404.

I am pointing to a www subdomain hosted remotely using a CNAME. I cannot place files on the remote server. Therefore, the files I am hosting at domain.com/links.html will not resolve to www.domain.com/links.html. I will get a 404 if I use the www. URL.

Can I solve this by scrapping the CNAME and using multiple A names? Or will this simply result in load sharing? I don't care about load sharing, I just want the machine to search multiple IPs for files prior to returning a 404.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible. HTTP can not delegate requests to other servers.

Whatever the intention of your strange setup is anyway, you are doing it wrong.

Comment: I have thousands of links pointing to my non-www root. Recently, my trade association has forced us to host content on a www subdomain hosted on their servers. They will not allow me to place the files on my non-www root on their servers. Therefore, I cannot use a 301 redirect to point my non-www files to a new location on the www servers. The end result is that I have 15 years worth of links pointing to the non-www domain and nothing to the www. domain. In the eyes of Google, the www domain is a separate site with no links pointing to it.

Comment: So stand up another server elsewhere to do the redirect.